# Any alternative to Universal Uploader (fireuploader) for Firefox?

Tags: download, firefox-extensions, upload

I can't use [Universal Uploader (fireuploader) for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/universal-uploader-fireuploade/) to upload/download from box.net anymore, I keep getting message "You are not logged in correctly" even my username and password are correct, is there any alternative for it ?